# How to hide a visual in power-bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Often there will be client requirement where the visual needs to be hidden unless selected upon or unless it meets certain criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power-Bi does not, at present offer this solution. However, there is a workaround for this.
I found this awesome article which explains how it can be done.

https://exceleratorbi.com.au/show-or-hide-a-power-bi-visual-based-on-selection/

You can go through the above link which explains how easily it can be done.

Credits to the creator.

Cheers :)